# Is there any way to set a header in an html email within the body of the email?

Tags: html-email

I have a client who needs some html mass emails sent.  I've coded the email, but for some reason, probably a problem with their mail client, the test emails they've received have been marked with low importance.

I believe I could override this by adding an x-priority header to the email, however the mass mail service I'm forced to use (have no choice about this unfortunately) won't allow me to customize headers.

Is it possible to set the header within the actual body of the email?  Are there html tags that allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Email HTML is just markup, and clients don't read the content for headers.

Which client are they using? Some clients (Hotmail, Gmail) analyse the content and assign their own rule, so there is no header you can change. This is done at the mailserver level, so if a user's client is, say, Thunderbird but their server is Gmail, it may still mark as low priority based on Gmail's rules.

If the client is Outlook and the mailserver is an in-house Postfix installation (for example), then you can set X Headers but by default, Outlook will strip them. For this reason, I suspect either the server or the client is setting the priority, it's not at the send level.

Look at the original source, and see whether or not it does contain the Priority header.